# Improved query performance of a recursive function

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I have a recursive function that calls another function and unions on the results.

Forward_Link_Traversal

```
if 
    depth_count > 0 and 
    exists(
        select child_service_item_id
        from service_item_links
        where parent_service_item_id = ANY(source_ids) and link_type = ANY(link_types) and company_id=cid and action_date <= end_time
    )
then   
    return query 
        select out_function.child_id as child_service_item_id
        from filter_latest_added_action(source_ids) out_function
        union select * from forwards_link_traversal(
            cid, 
            ARRAY(select in_function.child_id as child_service_item_id from filter_latest_added_action(source_ids) in_function), 
            link_types,
            depth_count - 1
        );
else
    return query
    select filter_function.child_id as child_service_item_id
    from filter_latest_added_action(source_ids) filter_function;
end if;
```

Where forward_link_traversal is the recursive function and filter_latest_added_action generates the result.

filter_latest_added_action is as follows:

```
return query with cte as (
      select *, first_value (action_key) over (partition by parent_service_item_id, child_service_item_id order by action_date desc) last_action_type
      from service_item_links
      where (parent_service_item_id = any(source_ids) or child_service_item_id = any(source_ids))
    )
    select child_service_item_id, parent_service_item_id 
    from cte
    where last_action_type = 'added'
  and link_type = ANY(link_types) 
  and company_id=cid
  and action_date <= end_time
  and (parent_service_item_id = any(source_ids) or child_service_item_id = any(source_ids))
  group by cte.parent_service_item_id, child_service_item_id;
```

The table (service_item_links) that it selects from is basically a many to many relationship between service_items. These items can be anything, and service_item_links just describes which is the parent and which is the child.

Links between items can be added or removed. The goal of the recursive function is to find all child of the inputted parent_id that have the latest action of 'added'. The schema for this looks like this:

| link_type | parent_service_item | child_service_item | action_date | action_key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'has_child' | 1 | 3 | '2020-01-01 00:00:00' | 'added' |
| 'has_child' | 1 | 3 | '2020-01-02 00:00:00' | 'removed' |
| 'has_child' | 1 | 3 | '2020-01-03 00:00:00' | 'added' |
| 'has_child' | 1 | 4 | '2020-01-01 00:00:00' | 'added |
| 'has_child' | 2 | 3 | '2020-01-01 00:00:00' | 'added' |
| 'has_child' | 2 | 4 | '2020-01-01 00:00:00' | 'added' |

Given the parent id of 1, the child id of 4 should be returned.
given the parent ids of {1,2}, the child if of 3 and 4 should be returned.

Problem is, this function is incredibly slow. I'm looking for advice on how to improve the speed of this. Is there a better way of finding the latest added action without using a group by? Or is there a way I could preform this at the very end of query, so the group by is only done once?

Explain Analyze on the recursive function (Which didn't seem to work out as intended):

```
Function Scan on forwards_link_traversal  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=46936.150..46936.221 rows=1474 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.032 ms
Execution Time: 46936.394 ms
```

Explain Analyze on filter_latest_added_action:

```
Group  (cost=78791.66..78791.67 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.095..0.100 rows=22 loops=1)
  Group Key: cte.parent_service_item_id, cte.child_service_item_id
  CTE cte
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=77263.22..77721.75 rows=20379 width=107) (actual time=0.053..0.071 rows=22 loops=1)
          ->  Sort  (cost=77263.22..77314.17 rows=20379 width=75) (actual time=0.046..0.048 rows=22 loops=1)
                Sort Key: service_item_links.parent_service_item_id, service_item_links.child_service_item_id, service_item_links.action_date DESC
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB
                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on service_item_links  (cost=429.32..75804.62 rows=20379 width=75) (actual time=0.028..0.033 rows=22 loops=1)
                      Recheck Cond: ((parent_service_item_id = ANY ('{751753846,751753847}'::bigint[])) OR (child_service_item_id = ANY ('{751753846,751753847}'::bigint[])))
                      Heap Blocks: exact=2
                      ->  BitmapOr  (cost=429.32..429.32 rows=20379 width=0) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=0 loops=1)
                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on service_item_links_from_service_item_id_640bede3  (cost=0.00..407.89 rows=20099 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=22 loops=1)
                                  Index Cond: (parent_service_item_id = ANY ('{751753846,751753847}'::bigint[]))
                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on service_item_links_to_service_item_id_8dbe9885  (cost=0.00..11.24 rows=280 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
                                  Index Cond: (child_service_item_id = ANY ('{751753846,751753847}'::bigint[]))
  ->  Sort  (cost=1069.91..1069.91 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.094..0.095 rows=22 loops=1)
        Sort Key: cte.parent_service_item_id, cte.child_service_item_id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
        ->  CTE Scan on cte  (cost=0.00..1069.90 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.058..0.088 rows=22 loops=1)
              Filter: (((last_action_type)::text = 'added'::text) AND (company_id = 1988) AND ((parent_service_item_id = ANY ('{751753846,751753847}'::bigint[])) OR (child_service_item_id = ANY ('{751753846,751753847}'::bigint[]))) AND ((link_type)::text = ANY ('{has_pull_request,has_commit,has_custom_field,has_custom_field_value,has_card_state,has_subtask,has_sprint,has_release,has_epic,has_build,has_action,has_child_issue,has_label,has_child_board,has_project,has_component,is_blocked_by,has_card_type}'::text[])))
Planning Time: 0.193 ms
Execution Time: 0.152 ms
```

Comment: please provide both sample data and desired output

Comment: The end of the answer has some sample data and the result of 2 different inputs, is there any other scenario's I can add?

Comment: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the problematic query?

Comment: @FrankHeikens I added the results of the explain analyze on running with a fair large input set. I'm not very familiar with explain analyze, so if the output isn't correct let me know.

Comment: Could you show us the code of forwards_link_traversal() ? And the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE from the queries that are executed within this function? I can see it takes some time to execute, but have no idea what's inside. The other query is fast, about 0.3 millisecond, there's not much you can do to improve that.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I added the full function to the top of the question. I can't seem to find a good way to explain / analyze the function as it's a recursive function. It looks like each call creates the execution plan separately, so I don't think there's a great way for me to get that.